# Listeners and instance variable scope [javafx]

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, listener

I cannot understand why I can't get proper values of my object inside a listener. I created an instance variable "plant" which is type of "Plant". Then in one of my methods I created a Plant object and assigned it to "plant variable". Then I set some fields of plant object like "name" and "id". Everything works fine but... I created a listener to open a new window after button click. And what is strange for me, inside this listener the program cannot see the plant object fields which I set earlier.
Here is my code:

```
class Plant {

    private plantName;
    private gridId;

    public String getName() {
        return plantName;
    }
    public void setName(String plantName) {
        this.plantName = plantName;
    }
    public int gridId() {
        return gridId;
    }
    public void setGridId(int gridId) {
        this.gridId = gridId;
    }
}
```

The following code presents fragment of GrowboxModel class where the fields for Plant object are setted:

```
public Plant selectAll(int gridId) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM plant WHERE gridId = ?";
    Plant plant = new Plant();
    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, gridId);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next()) {
            plant.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            plant.setGridId(resultSet.getInt("gridId"));
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
    return plant;
}
```

Below is fragment of my growboxController class:

```
public Plant plant;
public GrowboxModel model = new GrowboxModel();

private void growboxCellContent(VBox plantAreaVbox) {
        plant = model.selectAll(Integer.parseInt(plantAreaVbox.getId()));
        if (plant.getName() == null) {
            plantName.setText("EMPTY  " + plantAreaVbox.getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("FULL" + plant.getGridId());
        }
}
```

For now everything was great. The program the fields of plant object. But the problem is below:

```
public void growboxCellBehaviour(VBox plantAreaVbox) {  
    plantAreaVbox.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("NAME: " + plant.getName() + ", gridId: " + plant.getGridId());
        }
    });
}
```

It was a moment when "plant.getName()" etc. are null, although should have same name.

I know how to create a workaround but just wonder if anyone know why listener can't see these fields.

Comment: Where is defined plantName? It must be an attribute of Plant class. Methods getGridId() and getDescription() are missing too.

Comment: The values for `plantName` and `id` are never set.

Comment: Presumably you are not calling `getName()` on the same `Plant` instance on which you called `setName()`. (You haven't even shown anywhere where you call `setName()`, let alone enough to be able to tell why this is happening. Create a [MCVE].)

Comment: Sorry, I edited these gaps so it should be clear now. And I'm calling getName() on the same Plant instance and that's why it is so strange to me. When I pass the plant reference via method parameter it works but if it is global instance it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In the plant class, nothing is actually being assigned you need to actually set the variables.

```
class Plant {
String plantName;
int id;  
public String getName() {
    return plantName;
}
public void setName(String plantName1) {
    plantName = plantName1;
}
public int gridId() {
    return gridId;
}
public void setId(int id1) {
    id = id1;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when putted the code here. The variables exist and I edited the code to show that